# Magento admin dashboard order time is incorrect

Tags: magento, graph, dashboard

Magento times are off and none seem to agree with each other.

For example

```
Order and email placed at 6:06AM EST
Magento dashboard shows order placed at around 1:06AM
```

Comment: What have you done to find out what's wrong? Have you checked the time zone on the server etc?

Comment: Magento time zone is set to EST. Order date/time shows correct at admin > sales > orders i.e. 6:06AM but on dashboard it's off around 1:06AM.

Comment: Is it possible to get a screenshot of the dashboard so we can see what you mean? Thanks

Comment: Please view these links  

[Dashboard](http://i2.sqi.sh/s_3/eTF/dashboard.png)  

[Orders Screen](http://i2.sqi.sh/s_3/eTF/orders.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to System → Config → Sales → Sale → Dashboard And mark

> Use Aggregated Data (beta)="No"

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to “System->Configuration->General->Locale Options->Timezone” in Admin area of Magento, you’ll see that you can change Timezone for each Website you have. This way you get a way to have stores for each part of the world set with correct timezone. I assuming that you do not have set it properly.

*I hope this helps some more people.*